# Compare Jenkins Configuration for two different jobs

Tags: jenkins

I had a jenkins job, which was later cloned and modified. Now I'd like to compare the configurations for both jobs. Not the historical changes, not the results, but the configurations for both jobs.

Is it possible to compare the configuration for two Jenkins jobs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
diff $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/job1/config.xml $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/job2/config.xml
```

or

```
vimdiff $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/job1/config.xml $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/job2/config.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Mainframer is getting the answer, but I found a different way.

If you have access to the machine you can do a diff on the xml files. They are kept in the folders under " $JENKINS_HOME/jobs//config.xml".  However if you don't have access to the folders, you can still compare the jobs. Open "job configuration history" and download the latest from the two jobs and compare them with your favourite diff tool.

Comment: I believe "Job configuration history" is only present if you have the Job Config History plugin, but even without the plugin you can download the current config from Jenkins at `http://jenkins:8080/job/MYJOB/config.xml`

Comment: Thanks, @DaveBacher, if your diff tool supports urls you can just place them as you mentioned.

Comment: @DaveBacher you should have made your suggestion as an answer... Am I spoiled to not want to dig through the comments to find this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an existing plugin for Jenkins that will let you do this, but you can manually check the configuration files for each of these in something like notepad++ and highlight the differences between the files.

You can find the configuration files in their respective job/ folders, in the file named 'config.xml'