# Tell the difference between two Jenkins jobs from within Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm looking for a way to tell the difference between two Jenkins jobs ("projects") `JobA` and `JobB` from within Jenkins - for example, using some Groovy code that's running in the script console or as a build step.

(A similar question has been asked in [Compare Jenkins Configuration for two different jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680619/), but that's focused on diff-ing the XML job configuration files. A textual diff of those is problematic, since element order, amount of whitespace or inclusion of default values may differ on XML level, but still map to identical job specifications.)

Answer (score 0):

so, I assume you are using pipeline script and write code in jenkinsfile or in shared library. To do it in 'javish' way (which would possibly require sandbox off):

1. Grab job objects, you can do it via Jenkins instance:
   https://javadoc.jenkins.io/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html

`Jenkins.get().getItems(<your class>)` - will return all the jobs by specified type.

If you need any possible job - use `Job` as `<your class>`  - it is a parent class for all possible jenkins jobs - https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Job.html, otherwise try to narrow down the class you search.

2. Depending on what type you will have from the above function - you can compare all the possible parameters of the instances you get. Also, you can get and compare all the builds (runs) from that jobs.

hope that is smth you were looking for.

Comment: @Alex O, did it help? can the question be closed?